# How to set user attribute using devise user_id before_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Using devise, I'm trying to set a custom attribute automatically after a user is created.

Here is what I have in my User model.

```
 after_save :set_attribute_to_devise_id

 private

   def set_attribute_to_devise_id
    self.custom_attribute = self.id
   end
```

When a user registers and an account is created, the custom_attribute is not saving the ID that devise generated. However, when testing in the console, running User.save on the user seems to update the custom_attribute, but does not persist or save to the database permanently.

I've tried after_commit as well as after_create without any luck. How do I save the user.id from Devise automatically to another attribute column on user creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback should be `before_save` at max.
`after_save` is run when all the changes have been saved into the database, so in this case it is too late.

Comment: Thank you! This works - but it appears that the after_save callback isn't run automatically until the user has confirmed the account using devise confirmable. Which is OK, but I'm wondering why the attribute isn't updated when I see that a User is created upon registering in the console. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The method should be called always, as long as the validation passes. If in the console does not happen, restart the console so that it takes the changes.